# Is there a way to have a VB 6 app call a .NET assembly?

Tags: .net, vb6

I'm having trouble translating C# code to VB 6 (Haven't done that in a looooong while).  Is there a solution where I can code it in .NET and then have VB6 call the function instead?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, you could expose your managed assembly as COM object using the [regasm.exe](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tzat5yw6.aspx) utility. In order for the classes to be visible the assembly or individual classes need to be marked with the [`[ComVisible(true)]`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.comvisibleattribute.aspx) attribute. Once the assembly exposed as COM object you could consume it from VB6 as you would any standard COM object.

Answer (score 3):

To expose your .NET method to COM, you'll need to create an interface:

```
[Guid("CF4CDE18-8EBD-4e6a-94B4-6D5BC0D7F5DE")]
[InterfaceType(ComInterfaceType.InterfaceIsIDispatch)]
[ComVisible(true)]
public interface IFoo {

    [DispId(1)]
    string MyMethod(string value);
}
```

Your class will derive from the interface:

```
[Guid("7EBD9126-334C-4893-B832-706E7F92B525")]
[ClassInterface(ClassInterfaceType.None)]
[ComVisible(true)]
[ProgId("MyNamespace.Foo")]
public class Foo: IFoo {

    public string MyMethod(string value){
        return somestring;
    }
}
```

From VB6, your call will look something like:

```
Dim oFoo as New Foo
dim sReturn as string

sReturn = oFoo.MyMethod("someValue")
```